# How to passing variables between two modules which have a function?

Tags: python, variables, module

I stuck, i dont have idea how can I pass the variables to another module.

I have a package with modules:

```
Game_With_Function_Map.py
Game_informations.py
Game_Variables.py
```

In `Game_Variables.py` i have a variable:

```
floor = 1
moves = 0
moneys = 0
```

In `Game_informations.py` :

```
from game_variable import player_chests, money, floor, moves,

def informations(info):
    if info == "info":
        sorted(player_chests.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        print(
            f'\n[Money {money}],\n[Floor {floor}],\n[moves {moves}],\n[Ekwipunek]')
```

And in main file `Game_With_Function_Map.py`:

```
from Game_informations import informations as game_info
from game_variable import player_chests as player_chest
from game_variable import money
```

This code, change a value in game_variable

```
    else:
    global money
    player_chest[chest_color] -= 1
    add_gold = draw_money(
        chance_on_money[gold_in_chest[f'{chest_color}']])
    money = money + add_gold
    print('Added', add_gold, 'gold')
```

After moving variables to `game_variable.py` all working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `class variable` property here, where  same value is share among all classes instances and if  any change happen it happen in all instance

you can define variable as class instance and use them as it

code structure: `Game_Variables.py` file

```
class Variables:
    floor = 1
    moves = 0
    money = 0
```

and you can  use these function in other classes or modules as

```
from Game_Variables import Variables
from game_variable import player_chests, money, floor, moves,

def informations(info):
    if info == "info":
        sorted(player_chests.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        print(
            f'\n[Money {Variables.money}],\n[Floor {Variables.floor}],\n[moves {Variables.moves}],\n[Ekwipunek]'
```